# Installer Crashes in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ssd, crash

I have an ASUS Laptop with 512 Gigs of SSD and 8 Gigs of RAM. I tried installing Ubuntu 21.04 but installer crashes with error message

```
The installer encountered an copying files to the hard disk:
    
[Errno 5] Input/output error
    
This is often due to faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or faulty hard disk. It may help to clean 
CD/DVD, to burn CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits often  
available electronics suppliers), to check whether the disk is old and in need replacement, 
or to move system to a cooler environment.
```

I run memtest86 to check for bad memory but I've got no errors, The iso is not corrupted, I verified the sha256sums and I even checked for badsectors in the root partition I am going install,  Everything is okay, but still it crashes. Tried on another ASUS laptop with same model still crashes. What should I do?

Comment: You have the same problem on multiple devices, so it sounds like, the instiller media is the problem.  You should simply recreate the media.  Be sure you download it again.

Comment: How do you know the ISO is ok? Maybe it's not already before download.

Comment: The error is, "faulty CD/DVD disk or drive," i.e., *installation media*. How is the installation media formatted? If USB, avoid exFAt - FAT32 is usually recommended.

Comment: @Ramhound, I tried to burn using Balena and also using dd utility in linux. I've installed other OS.No such problems,! tom463 I verified the sha256sums.

Comment: @Jonathan - You are asking our advice, the error message is literally indicating the problem, is the installation media.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I am, Installation media means USB stick I used to burn the iso right? If yes, I doubt it's the issue because I installed fedora and Rhel , by burning using balena etcher. I also tried  dd utility in linux.

Comment: Have you tried to redownload the ISO and recreate the media?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I recreated the media thrice and downloaded the iso twice